# MVC Rewriting URL

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, url-rewriting, asp.net-mvc-routing

I've an Ajax call that write a dynamic Url for some product.

`$("#Scheda").html( '<a href="/Frutta_e_Verdura/SchedaProdotto?idProdotto=' + result.Idprodotto + '&nome=' + result.Title + '" target = "_blank" >Scopri di più sul prodotto >>></a>' );`

The result link is :

`Frutta_e_Verdura/SchedaProdotto?idProdotto=83&nome=anacardi`

I want turn it with routeconfig in the form:

`Frutta_e_Verdura/SchedaProdotto/anacardi`

I am trying with this routeconfig:

`routes.MapRoute(
               name: "prodotti",
               url: "frutta_e_verdura/schedaprodotto/{nome}/{idprodotto}",
               defaults: new { controller = "frutta_e_verdura", action = "Index", nome = UrlParameter.Optional ,idprodotto = UrlParameter.Optional }
           );`

How can i do this?

Thank you all for your availability

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Routing is for mapping an incoming URL to a resource, not to change the URL in the browser. The only way to do that is to use a 302 or 301 redirect.

But, as redirecting the URL is going to cause your server to send a response to the client instructing it to do *another* request to the server, this is an unnecessary round trip across the network.

Your best option is just to write the URL correctly from your AJAX call to match the `prodotti` route you have defined to avoid this unnecessary redirect.

```
$("#Scheda").html( '<a href="/Frutta_e_Verdura/SchedaProdotto/' + result.Title + '/' + 
    result.Idprodotto + '" target = "_blank" >Scopri di più sul prodotto >>></a>' );
```

Comment: I'm sorry but I think that it isn't exactly as you say.  I have this url http://website.com/Frutta_e_Verdura/SchedaProdotto?idProdotto=83&nome=anacardi and I have to make a rewriting of the URL to make it seo friendly. How can i do this?